# Need assistance with a regular expression

Tags: regex

This is what I currently have:

```
(\d+).*?\s+(.+)
```

I'd like it to work for the following:

```
1x apple
10x Apple seeds
5 carrots
100xPotatoes
```

I tried adding [x]? for the last one but it doesn't seem to work? Basically the x may or may not be there.

Comment: `(\d+)[xX]?\s*(.*)` or `^(\d+)[xX]?\s*(.*?)$` is probably a little better if you're looking at whole strings.

Comment: The problem with 100xPotatos is the missing space your regex requires: `(\d+).*?[\sx]+(.+)`

Comment: @wp78de -  5 xylophones :)  (Yeah, pretty unlikely)

Comment: What should I do for a fruit that starts with x? Like xigua?

Comment: Unfortunately there could be foods like Xanthan Gum.

Comment: Actually it looks like @zzxyz answer works well. :)

Comment: @rotaercz - I'd probably change `[xX]` to just `x` if you know you don't have strings like `1X apple` and objects that start with x are a possibility.

Comment: Yeah, I already did. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these will match your test cases:

```
^(\d++).*?[x\s](\S.*)$
^(\d+)(?:x?\s+|x(?=[A-Z]))(.+)
```

You don't have any distractors to show what should not match, so I don't know how aggressive to be.  The first regex is much shorter albeit slower than the second regex.

The [first regex](https://regex101.com/r/LTg1Mm/1) uses a possessive quantifier to prevent backtracking, ensuring that all leading digits are captured in `\1`, then lazily matches any number of characters before an `x` or a space character, after which it captures a non-space character and everything after it into `\2`.

The [second regex](https://regex101.com/r/LTg1Mm/2) consumes digits into `\1` and then needs either an optional `x` and a space or else a `x` followed by a capital letter (which we use a lookahead for so it is available for the second capture), then it captures the rest in `\2`.